# Rails: database-handling for an international ecommerce app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, internationalization

**Edited**
The question in short:
Is there a way (a gem?) in Rails to bind two databases of same schemes to an app, where Rails decides which db to use on top level domain?

For example: if user entered example.de the data on site loads from a db called de_example_production and if it's example.com then the data is loaded from us_example_production.

Details (old question):

I have an ecommerce Rails app that has been developed for some particular country. Now I am trying to extend it to another country.

The main requirement is that it should be the same app running on the same server (so that code updates apply to all countries), but since the countries have different data - cities, stores, products - I want to them to be on separate databases. What's the best way to achieve this?

As an alternative, I thought of continuing with the current database by adding a country model on top of the hierarchy of models that I already have, but it seems to me this approach will add a lot of complexity and redundancy to the system.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: If you have some specific piece of code you need help out with we would be happy to help you out with it but StackOverflow is not suited for large architectural questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, Jared! I've rephrased the question.

Comment: The term you're looking for is `Multitenacy`.

Comment: Danke, Thomas! Thant's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas pointed out, the paradigm I was looking for is called **multitenancy**. I decided to proceed with the [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem as it perfectly suited my requirements.

These pro railscasts helped me in my implementation:
[Multitenancy with Scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes)
and Multitenancy with PostgreSQL.